# Using DBSet<> which creates circular reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference

I can't seem to figure out how to reference my class that is in another dll (in the same solution) using the EntityFramework

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Animal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I try to add the reference I will that it would create a circular reference.

```
public class AnimalDBContext : DbContext
{
    public AnimalDBContext()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

}
```

This is the version that seems more correct to me. But it might not?

```
public class AnimalDBContext<TEntity> where TEntity  : DbContext
{
    public AnimalDBContext()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<TEntity> Animals { get; set; }

}
```

This leads to the following compiler error.

```
 AnimalDBContext < Animal > animal = new AnimalDBContext<Animal>();

Error   3   The type 'AnimalLibrary.Animals.Animal' cannot be used as type
parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method
ObjectSaver.AnimalDBContext<TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
AnimalLibrary.Animals.Animal' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.
```

Comment: Have you added the reference to the other project which provides the class `Animal`?

Comment: @Matten I think that's what is creating the circular reference.

Comment: Well still if I don't know how to reference the <Animal> in this case I can create the datamodel for it. I have tried using the <TEntity> instead but that gives other problems.

Comment: @user2130951 your dependency is backwards - the assembly that `Animal` is in should not need to reference the assembly that `AnimalDBContext` is in.

Comment: The library needs to save to the database. Why should I not reference the "application saver"? Instead why would the saver reference the logic of the business logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I understand right, your "repository" assembly references your "domain" assembly, which makes sense, and your "domain" assembly references your "repository" assembly, which does not.

Your entity classes should not reference the repository that is used to create them for several reasons:

- It creates a circular dependency, as you have discovered
- It makes it much more difficult to mock your classes for unit testing
- You entity is tied to one type of provider, making it difficult to change providers in the future

Move the dependencies on the repository from the domain into a separate assembly.

Based on your comment it sounds like you need at least three assemblies -

- A) data access,
- B) business logic, and
- C) domain classes.

*Ideally* A and B should reference C but not each other (or vice versa).  Your domain classes do not need to know how to persist themselves - that's someone else's responsibility.

You *could* reference B from A but that prevents you from "mocking" your repository to test your business logic.  Tying the data access and business logic would be in a "service" layer that your main application references.  Again, you *could* bundle the service and application layer together, but this also increases coupling and reduces testability.